# How to call JavaScript after Spring validation get success?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am doing a Chat project in Spring.It consists of only one JSP page.

In that jsp I have two input text boxes (name,message), a send button and a text area to append the messages. I did the textbox validation using Spring Annotations.

I need to call a JavaScript function , when the spring controller returns a success string.

How can I call a JavaScript function to do the Ajax call when the Spring validation returns success?

Answer (score 0):

In the view rendered by spring simply add the execution of a javascript function

with jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
dotheajaxcall();
});
```

isn't it simplier as this ?or maybe I didn't understand the problem.

Comment: Shall we do the discussion in chat ?

Comment: I cant do this with `$(document).ready(function(){});` . Because I have only one JSP page for my project

Comment: your jsp can write it depending on a condition, if the validation pass you write it to the page otherwise you don't ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Normally javaScript will be loaded when the jsp page gets loaded in first time.So first time my jsp runs in browser, It executes the javascript `$(document).ready(function(){});` before moving to the spring validation. ???

Comment: ok, how is performed the spring validation ? doesn't it send a request and reload the page ?
Or maybe it an ajax request in this case you can execute the dotheajaxcall() in the onsuccess: event